# How can I resolve this error regarding dbt templater? Templater cannot be set in a .sqlfluff file in a subdirectory of the current working directory

Tags: dbt, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com, dbt-bigquery

I am trying to use dbt templater with pre-commit hooks, but I am constantly receiving this error message:

`Attempt to set templater to dbt failed. Using jinja templater. Templater cannot be set in a .sqlfluff file in a subdirectory of the current working directory. It can be set in a .sqlfluff in the current working directory. See Nesting section of the docs for more details.`

However, my .sqlfluff file is in the root directory (same location as my .pre-commit-config.yaml file.

This is my .sqlfluff file:

```
[sqlfluff]
templater = dbt
dialect = bigquery
rules = core
max_line_length = 120

[sqlfluff:templater:dbt]
project_dir = ./
apply_dbt_builtins = true


[sqlfluff:indentation]
indent_unit = space
tab_space_size = 4
indented_joins = false

[sqlfluff:rules:capitalisation.keywords]
capitalisation_policy = lower

[sqlfluff:rules:capitalisation.functions]
extended_capitalisation_policy = lower

[sqlfluff:templater:jinja]
apply_dbt_builtins = True
```

and this is my pre-commit-config.yaml file:

```
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff
  rev: 2.1.2
  hooks:
    - id: sqlfluff-lint
      additional_dependencies: ['bigquery', 'sqlfluff-templater-dbt']
    - id: sqlfluff-fix
      additional_dependencies: ['bigquery', 'sqlfluff-templater-dbt']
```

Without the pre-commit hooks, the .sqlfluff file works fine with dbt templater by just running sqlfluff-fix. With the pre-commit hooks it just defaults to the jinja templater, but it runs.

I have checkout [this link on nesting](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html#nesting) but I can't seem to find out the issue and why it is not working as it should. I also tried adding [sqlfluff:templater:dbt]
project_dir = ./ but it does not work.

Comment: can you show the output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` and the location of `.sqlfluff` relative to that?

Comment: /Users/user/data-foundations-data-transformations and /Users/user/data-foundations-data-transformations/data_accelerator/.sqlfluff

Answer (score 0):

> my .sqlfluff file is in the root directory (same location as my .pre-commit-config.yaml file.

from your clarification in the comment, this is **not true**:

> /Users/user/data-foundations-data-transformations and /Users/user/data-foundations-data-transformations/data_accelerator/.sqlfluff

`pre-commit` always executes from the root of the repository -- independent of where you place the `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file.

as such, `sqlfluff` is only finding your `.sqlfluff` file in a `./data_accelerator` subdirectory and is correctly giving the error you see

you'll want to move that and the pre-commit configuration to the top level directory.  there is only one set of git hooks for a single repository so there is intentionally no "monorepo" support for pre-commit.

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: We have a similar situation in our project, where we have pre-commit at the root level yet 3 DBT projects inside, as separate folders. Each folder represents a different environment.

We created a `.sqlfluff` file in the root with the following structure:
`[sqlfluff] templater = dbt`.

Then in each DBT project folder we have another `.sqlfluff` file with the project-specific configuration relative to the root, for example: `[sqlfluff:templater:dbt] project_dir = dev/dbt \ profiles_dir = dev/dbt`

Yet this doesn't work, as the profile/project dir are not found this way.. @anthony-sottile

Comment: @LucianMoldovanu did you read the answer you're replying to?  it tells you why that will not work

Comment: I did :) but I also read the docs [here](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html#nesting), from where I understand that I can declare the templater in the root .sqlfluff, yet I can also define a .sqlfluff file in subfolders which will be combined with the root .sqlfluff file (the specific properties declared in the subfolder file taking precendence over the general).

Yet what I realize is that pre-commit/sqlfluff probably don't have a mechanism to check each file (in a commit) against its' own project-specific sqlfluff, thus it cannot work with repos with 1+ dbt projects?